# No module named 'PyQt5.sip' even if I just installed it

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, pyqt5

I am using Ubuntu VM and trying to run a GUI script - [this is the entire repo](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/tree/python3) and [this is the script](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller/blob/python3/Scripts/CellModellerGUI.py). Apparently I didn't need to install PyQt5, because it said `Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in ./.eggs/PyQt5-5.14.2-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (5.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 in ./.eggs/PyQt5_sip-12.7.2-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (from pyqt5) (12.7.2).`

However, when running the script, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Scripts/CellModellerGUI.py", line 9, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.sip'
```

So I installed it with pip, but I get the exact same error.

I tried pyqt5-sip, too, but "Requirement already satisfied" appeared again.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your pip and python are not linked to the same version. Try doing `pip --version` and `python --version` and see if the Python versions match (not the pip version, but the Python version it says it's linked to)

Comment: It says: pip 20.0.2 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/cellmodeller/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8) and Python 3.8.2

Comment: /home/me/anaconda3/envs/cellmodeller/bin/python. Context: the only thing I installed on this VM was Anaconda, cloning the Gut repo, creating an environment cellmodeller, running setup.py install and then the only thing left is to run this GUI script.